# Issue with output of tap operator in RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am confused with the output of the below code, as per the take(3) processing should stop after rendering 10, but still getting 5,6 and 9 from tap operator. Please refer below output and code snippet.

- Tapped value null
- Tapped value 20
- Rendering Item 20
- Tapped value 15
- Rendering Item 15
- Tapped value 10
- Rendering Item 10
- Completed
- Tapped value 5
- Tapped value 6
- Tapped value 9

```
of(null, 20, 15, 10, 5, 6, 9)
      .pipe(
        tap(val => console.log(`Tapped value ${val}`)),
        filterNil(),
        take(3)
      )
      .subscribe(
        item => console.log(`Rendering Item ${item}`),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('Completed')
      );
  }

const filterNil = () => (source: Observable<any>) =>
  new Observable(observer => {
    return source.subscribe({
      next(value) {
        if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
          observer.next(value);
        }
      },
      error(error) {
        observer.error(error);
      },
      complete() {
        observer.complete();
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The final answer to this question**

The correct answer to this question is provided by the [following post](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5369#issuecomment-607486466).

**My first answer - a simplistic answer**

What you see depends on the fact that your code is completely synchronous, and therefore the `unsubscribe` after 3 emissions, which is implicit in `take(3)`, does not have the chance to run.

Look at this version

```
of(null, 20, 15, 10, 5, 6, 9)
      .pipe(
        delay(0),  // >>> intruduce a delay
        tap(val => console.log(`Tapped value ${val}`)),
        filterNil(),
        take(3)
  )
```

Here you introduce a `delay`, which gives `take` the possibility to `unsubscribe` and, as a consequence, you see the behavior which you expect.

**Not an answer but a more detailed reasoning**

I have investigated a bit more into this problem and I have found some things which make my previous answer a bit too simple.

Let's start from the fact that `filterNil()` is a legitimate custom operator that should do the same as `filter(item => item !== null)`, where `filter` is an operator provided by `rxjs/operators`, i.e. by the library.

Now, if we substitute `filter(item => item !== null)` to `filterNil()` in the `pipe` we obtain a different result

```
of(null, 20, 15, 10, 5, 6, 9)
      .pipe(
        tap(val => console.log(`Tapped value ${val}`)),
        filter(item => item !== null),
        take(3)
      )

      .subscribe(
        item => console.log(`Rendering Item ${item}`),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('Completed')
      );
  }

// the output on the console is

Tapped value null
Tapped value 20
Rendering Item 20
Tapped value 15
Rendering Item 15
Tapped value 10
Rendering Item 10
Completed
```

This means that `filter(item => item !== null)` and `filterNil()` are not equivalent.

The fact that they are not equivalent seems to come from the implementation of the `subscribe` method of `Observable` joint with the somehow different nature of `filterNil` and `filter`.

When using `filterNil`, the trace of the execution of `subscribe` method of Observable is this

[image]

If, on the other hand, we use `filter` operator, the execution trace of of `subscribe` method of Observable is this
[image]

Therefore the fact that `filterNil` does have the `operator` attribute set to null while `filter` does have the `operator` attribute set to `FilterOperator` seems to drive the different behavior. The reasons behind are not clear to me and are worth a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `filterNil` function is still running because that is a new observable that is not affected by the `take` operator. RxJS operators run in order. You can move the `take` to the initial position in the pipe, or I would recommend not creating a new observable in your filter function

```js
// operator position matters
.pipe(
  take(3)
  tap(val => console.log(`Tapped value ${val}`)),
  filterNil()
)

// Or re-factored filterNil operator

const filterNilRefactor = () => {
  return source => source.pipe(filter((value) => value !== undefined && value !== null))
}

.pipe(
  tap(val => console.log(`Tapped value ${val}`)),
  filterNilRefactor(),
  take(3)
)
```